# ‘Gen’ as a synonym for Attorney?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms, american-english

The Words With Friends dictionary tells me that ‘Gen’ means attorney,
Is this a general term for lawyers?
Does it have any special connotations?
Is it office slang?
How is it pronounced; like gin?

Comment: You'd only pronounce it like *gin* if you pronounce *pen* and *pin* the same way (that is, if you have the pen/pin merger, which lots of Americans have, particularly in the South).

Comment: I note the tag, so an aside that 'attorney' isn't a general term for lawyers in UK, and 'Atty' doesn't mean anything to a BrE speaker.

Comment: I've never heard any word resembling "gen" used in the US to mean "attorney".

Comment: I wonder if you might be conflating a different term, *Attorney General*? In that case, *gen* would be an adjective describing what type of attorney.

Comment: The appropriate form of address for the Attorney General of the United States is “General.”

Comment: Actually, in [Words With Friends](https://www.word-grabber.com/words-with-friends-cheat), GEN means "information" or "knowledge," not attorney. You pronounce it like the GEN in GENeration. Playing it will earn you 6 points in the game. But in the real world, I'd consider GEN to be short for generation but you rarely see this abbreviation.

Comment: No, gen is not a synonym for attorney.

Comment: [The WWF dictionary allows 'qgp' as a word](https://wordfinder.yourdictionary.com/unscramble/q_p/) with definition: "Initialism
(physics) quark-gluon plasma". So if it allows that then I figure almost anything goes.

Answer (score 3):

No, "Gen" meaning lawyer is unknown to most dictionaries.  (However they have other definitions for "gen" so it is allowed to be played.)

"gen" can mean "information".  The *OED* says it originated as R.A.F. slang.

Other dictionaries have also "gen" used as slang for "generation".

Comment: On WWF and "other definitions ... allowed to be played," they disallow almost all abbreviations (except VIP), but display definitions of allowed words as their disallowed versions.